# KML description overshadows ExtendedData

Tags: kml

I have a placemark feature containing some ExtendedData fields as a KML file. I would also like to include a description for this placemark, and have both the description and the ExtendedData appear in the balloon for the placemark.

The problem is, when I bring any modification to the description, all ExtendedData fields disappear, and are replaced by the newly entered description. However I know they are still there because when I copy the placemark into a text editor I can see that both tags are still there.

Is there any way to have both the description and the placemark appear in the balloon at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Earth displays the extended data fields formatted as HTML-table in the pop-up description box only when the description field of the placemark or feature is missing. If a feature contains a description then that description text is what is displayed when a user clicks on that feature in a pop-up description box.

If you want to have both extended data fields and a custom description then you can either 1) duplicate the data in the description or 2) use a shared [BallonStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#balloonstyle) with the [ExtendedData](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#extendeddata) names as placeholders in a template.

Here is a simple example of using ExtendedData with a BalloonStyle:
http://kml-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/kml/ExtendedData/data-golf.kml

Tutorial including using the BalloonStyle element as a template:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata

Comment: Thanks, this was quite useful. Is there a way to enter code into the description such that it updates the extended data field(s) in the kml? Ultimately what I would like to do is have the description update the extended data fields as a quick way for non-programmers to update the kml...

Comment: Whatever is in the extendedData will appear in the description if use BalloonStyle and template place holders for each of the fields.